# Multithreading - loading

Tags: python, multithreading

I want write loading for my script

```
thread_1 >> its my loading function (only print>> #), this is loop
thread_2 >> print number 1 to 100
```

I want `thread_1` start after `thread_2` starts
when `thread_2` finished
I want `thread_1` stop

My code in python:

```
import time
import threading

def thread_1():
   while(True):
      print('#')
      time.sleep(1)
def thread_2():
   i=1
   n=100
   for i in range(n):
      print('a'+str(i))

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_1, args=())
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_2, args=())
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
if(thread2.is_alive()==False):
   thread1.kill()
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import time
import multiprocessing

def thread_1():
   while(True):
      print('#')
      time.sleep(1)

def thread_2():
   i=1
   n=100
   for i in range(n):
      print('a'+str(i))

thread1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=thread_1, args=())
thread2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=thread_2, args=())
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

**Pause-Resume**

```py
while True:
    if not thread2.is_alive():
        thread1.suspend()
    else:
        thread1.resume()
```

**Terminate**

```py
while True:
    if not thread2.is_alive():
        thread1.terminate()
        break
```

Comment: sorry but dont work

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `python-worker` to stop your thread ([link](https://pypi.org/project/python-worker/))

```
import time
from worker import worker

@worker
def thread_1():
   while(True):
      print('#')
      time.sleep(1)

@worker
def thread_2():
   i=1
   n=100
   for i in range(n):
      print('a'+str(i))

thread2_worker = thread_2()
thread1_worker = thread_1()

while not thread2_worker.is_alive():
    thread1_worker.abort()
```

here you `thread_1` and `thread_2` function will be executed as threads with `@worker` decorator

Answer (score 0):

Below is a variation of your example program that meets your stated requirements.  I added some more `print()` statements to make it more obvious in the output when each thread starts and stops.

```
import time
import threading

thread_1_please_die = False

def thread_1():
   print('thread1 is starting now')
   while(thread_1_please_die == False):
      print('#')
      time.sleep(1)
   print('thread1 is exiting now')

def thread_2():
   print('thread2 is starting now')

   thread1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_1, args=())
   thread1.start()

   i=1
   n=100
   for i in range(n):
      print('a'+str(i))

   global thread_1_please_die
   thread_1_please_die = True
   thread1.join()  # blocks here until thread1 has exited

   print('thread2 is exiting now')

print('main thread is starting now')
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_2, args=())
thread2.start()
thread2.join()    # blocks here until thread2 has exited
print('main thread is exiting now')
```